# What is the Silverlight 3.0 equivalent for BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am trying to extend a base style for a TextBlock. Simple think in WPF world, should be the same in Silverlight. But I get a error on x:Type.

How can I translate BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" in Silverlight.
 Anyone out there who achieved this ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can actually do this now in Silverlight 5. See my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent to that particular usage in Silverlight.  Silverlight only supports string keys for accessing Resources.  Hence the use of `{x:Type SomeType}` as a key doesn't work.

In Silverlight you need to make a complete copy of the controls style.  You can do this either by using Blend which has tools for doing this or by copy'n'pasting it from the Silverlight documentation. [Control Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc278075(VS.95).aspx)

Of course once you have a copy of the initial style you can then either modify your copy or create other Styles assigning this copy to BasedOn to create a set of variations.

Comment: Hi Anthony,

 I was afraid someone will say this, well nothing to do then to get to work then :(

Answer (score 3):

I Think it will work to go a little backwards, you can make your base style

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="PropertyName" Value="PropertyValue" />
</Style>
```

then you can base all buttons on that style

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" />
```

Then if you need to add to that style you can just base it on the named style

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="PropertyName" Value="PropertyValue" />
</Style>
```

or

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" x:Key="MyOtherButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="PropertyName" Value="PropertyValue" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

should ought to be (and [according to Jesse Liberty](http://jesseliberty.com/2009/07/18/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-sl3-%E2%80%93-based-on-styles/)) 
 `BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlock}"`

Comment: Hi Muad'Dib,

 I get "Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key TextBlock" witch is actually not true because I am clearly using the TwilightBlueTheme from the silverlight toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this now in Silverlight 5.

First, declare your style

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{local:Type TypeName=TextBox}">

</Style>
```

Next, you need to create a MarkupExtension which works in both WPF and Silverlight 5 to replace x:Type

```
/// A MarkupExtension which introduces x:Type like syntax to both WPF and Silverlight (Cross-platform). This is used internally
/// for the themes, but is also useful e.g. when creating custom Control Templates for SciChart
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Licensed under the CodeProject Open License
/// http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/305932/Static-and-Type-markup-extensions-for-Silverlight
/// </remarks>
/// 
public class TypeExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TypeExtension" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public TypeExtension()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TypeExtension" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type to wrap</param>
    public TypeExtension(Type type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the type information for this extension.
    /// </summary>
    public System.Type Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the type name represented by this markup extension.
    /// </summary>
    public String TypeName { get; set; }

    public override Object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Type == null)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TypeName)) throw new InvalidOperationException("No TypeName or Type specified.");
            if (serviceProvider == null) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            IXamlTypeResolver resolver = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IXamlTypeResolver)) as IXamlTypeResolver;
            if (resolver == null) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            Type = resolver.Resolve(TypeName);
        }
        return Type;
    }
}
```

Tested as working in WPF and Silverlight